# Origin of 'Dutch Courage'

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms, origin-unknown

I was wondering if anyone could shed some more definite light on the origin of the phrase 'Dutch Courage.'

I have found two, almost certainly apocryphal, origins:

> 1: From the [Thirty Years War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War) in the 17th Century, where British soldiers drank a Dutch Gin for it's warming/calming effects.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_courage)

and

> 2: Deriving "from the disparaging idea that Johnny Foreigner, whether sailing up the Medway or facing down the locals in the East Indies, needed a few drinks before a fight."[3](http://www.historyextra.com/qa/dutch-courage)

However, the phrase only seems to begin appearing in print from the [mid- to late-19th Century](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/43146?rskey=yjdNag&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid8120844) - some 200 years after its supposed coinage. Which makes me suspect there is another story behind this.

Unfortunately, as with many popular folk etymologies they swamp any other potential sources, so I look to EL&U for some help.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to look for some *specific* reason why ***dutch courage*** took hold. There are many other usages *(dutch auction, dutch uncle, double dutch, dutch wife)* where the (often somewhat derogatory, presumably on account of national rivalry) term simply means something along the lines of ***not the real thing***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was not previously aware of the usage of "dutch" as a rough synonym for "ersatz", but it appears to check out.  Etymonline.com says it's been in use since the 1600's as a "pejorative label pinned by English speakers on almost anything they regard as inferior, irregular, or contrary to 'normal' (i.e., their own) practice".

Comment: “Dutch” was productive in English from the early 17th century, through the 18th and, (spurred on by wars against the Dutch in the 1780s/90s), into the 19th century (further encouraged by rivalry in trade). It seems to have died out in the early 20th century. In this use, it has generally had a disparaging humour to it. The last coining in the OED is **Dutch party**  n. (see Dutch treat n.) 1927 *Dutch parties are [where] the hostess provides the dance floor, music, table, service, and cutlery, her friends bring along the drinks and the viands, raiding their family cellars and larders.*

Answer (score 1):

***[Dutch courage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dutch-courage):***

> - False courage acquired by drinking liquor, as in He had a quick drink to give him Dutch courage. ***This idiom alludes to the reputed heavy drinking of the Dutch, and was first referred to in Edmund Waller's Instructions to a Painter (1665):***
>
>   - “***The Dutch their wine, and all their brandy lose, Disarm'd of that from which their courage grows.”***.

(The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary)

The following ***[source](http://www.historyextra.com/qa/dutch-courage)*** cites two possible origins, but the "gin" related one appear to support the above assumption:

> - In many ways, the Dutch used to be Britain’s closest neighbours. From the rise of the United Provinces during the reign of Elizabeth I until the eclipse of the Netherlands as a major power in the Napoleonic wars, they were sometimes enemies but more usually co-religionist allies, important trading partners and occasional colonial rivals. And, of course a Dutchman, William, became king of England in 1689.
> - These connections are evident in our language: slang dictionaries are full of expressions such as ‘going Dutch’, ‘Dutch auction’ and ‘Dutch uncle’.
>
> ***‘Dutch courage’ has two possible origins:***
>
> - ***The first derives from the disparaging idea that Johnny Foreigner, whether sailing up the Medway or facing down the locals in the East Indies,***  needed a few drinks before a fight.
> - ***The second theory relates more directly to the use of a specific drink – gin – to bolster one’s courage.***
> - ***Gin in its modern form was reputedly invented by the Dutch physician Franz de le Boë (Franciscus Sylvius) in the 17th century.***  British troops fighting Louis XIV alongside their allies in the Low Countries appreciated the calming effects of Jenever (Dutch gin) before heading into battle. Cheap gin was widely available in London by the early 18th century.
> - Whether or not it specifically referred to gin, ‘Dutch courage’ as an English colloquialism tended to mean using spirits, not just beer, to stiffen resolve.

(www.historyextra.com)

Comment: When I've heard "Dutch courage", I've always pictured liquor, and specifically liquor which was consumed covertly, usually gin or brandy. I didn't realize it was more general than that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by user66974 correctly notes that an allusion to Dutch courage as flowing from a bottle of spirits appears in the course of a lengthy poem by Edmund Waller, "[Instructions to a Painter for the Drawing of a Picture of the State and Posture of the English Forces at Sea, Under the Command of His Royal Highness in the Conclusion of the Year 1664](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A67334.0001.001/1:1?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=brandy+lose)" (1665), which reads, in part, as follows:

> Our first success in War, make Bacchus crown, / And half the Vintage of the year our own; / **The Dutch their Wine, and all their Brandy lose,** / **Dis-arm'd of that from which their Courage grows.** / While the glad English to relieve their Toyl, / In Healths to their great Leader drink the spoyl.

The description here seems to involve the capture of Dutch ships loaded with wine and brandy—but the suggestion, unmistakably, is that the Dutch sailors relied on drinking alcohol to bolster their bravery.

Nevertheless, the earliest Google Books match for the exact phrase "Dutch courage" in connection with imbibing alcohol is from more than a century later. From "[Interesting Particulars of the Late Engagement Between Admirals Hyde Parker and Zoutman](https://books.google.com/books?id=icVJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA517&dq=%22dutch+courage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqvbPolfb1AhU9JUQIHZKuBSMQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22dutch%20courage%22&f=false)" in *The Political Magazine and Parliamentary, Naval, Military, and Literary Journal* (September 1781):

> In another part of the same letter [from Captain Decker of the *Bellona* to the *Amsterdam Gazette*, published on August 17, 1781], the writer in the true stile of rhodomontade says, "our Captain showed himself a hero and a lion in the midst of the fire ; and the crew were so full of zeal, that it was with great difficulty they were kept from firing, in their fury, into our own vessels. If this story is true, it is very probable the Dutch sailors were drunk. **Dutch courage** has been long proverbial.

The word *rhodomontade* derives from the character Rodomonte in Matteo Boiardo's *Orlando Innamorato* (1612) and means (according *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) "a bragging speech" or "vain boasting or bluster: rant." So, on the one hand, we have a surprisingly late first confirmed print occurrence of the expression "Dutch courage" in the sense of "alcohol-fueled bravery" and, on the other, an assertion in that very same occurrence that the expression "has been long proverbial" in English.

Instances of "Dutch courage" in the relevant sense become much more frequent from the early 1800s onward.

From Thomas Trotter, [*An Essay, Medical, Philosophical, and Chemical, on Drunkenness and Its Effects on the Human Body*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_ZVkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22dutch+courage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqvbPolfb1AhU9JUQIHZKuBSMQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22dutch%20courage%22&f=false), second edition (1804):

> It is well known that the modern armies of France are much addicted to drinking spirits; and many of their greatest victories are said to have been obtained under the fury inspired by dram-drinking; the spirits being supplied to the soldiers while engaged, by women who attended them for that service. This is a species of prowess which our tars call ***Dutch courage***; and which, I hope, will never be resorted to by Britons in the present contest with France.

From Diedrich Knickerbocker [Washington Irving], [*A History of New York*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AvwXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22dutch+courage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqvbPolfb1AhU9JUQIHZKuBSMQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22dutch%20courage%22&f=false) (1809):

> The bewildered Swede [Risingh] staggered with the blow [from Peter Stuyvesant's wooden leg], and in the mean time the wary Peter, espying a pocket pistol lying hard by (which had dropped from the wallet of his faithful squire and trumpeter Van Corlear during his furious encounter with the drummer) discharged it full at the head of the reeling Risingh—Let not my reader mistake—it was not a murderous weapon loaded with powder and ball, but a little sturdy stone pottle, charged to the muzzle with a double dram of true **dutch courage**, which the knowing Van Corlear always cried about with him by way of replenishing his valour.

And from "[Supplemental Journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=pzhOAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1593&dq=%22dutch+courage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiihbqphff1AhWAKEQIHdXjBUg4FBDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22dutch%20courage%22&f=false)" (April 1, 1812) in *The Debates and Proceedings in the Congress of the United States*, volume 2 (1853):

> Mr. RANDOLPH then said, that the step we are about taking is too high a price to pay for the consistency of gentlemen who think they have gone too far to recede; it is too expensive to bolster them up in this way. He asked what will be the situation of this people in sixty days? Put your note into the bank, and see how soon it will be out. What will be the sitution of this unhappy, misguided country? What would it have been for sixty, one hundred, or three hundred and sixty-five days past? He had hoped not to have seen the old story of the dog worrying the cat, &c., realized. Are the majority, in consequence of having been goaded by the presses, to plunge the people into war by bringing them first to the whipping post and then by exciting their spirit? He would assure the House the spirit of the people is not up to it at this time; if so there would be no necessity of those provocations to excite this false spirit—this kind of **Dutch courage**. If you mean war, if the spirit of the country is up to it, why have you been spending five months in idle debate?

Here, "Dutch courage" is used figuratively for "false bravado," with little or no literal connection to alcohol consumption.

And from David Porter, [*Journal of a Cruise Made to the Pacific Ocean in the United States Frigate Essex*](https://books.google.com/books?id=D18PAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA183&dq=%22dutch+courage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj--uGi_fb1AhVQH0QIHXl8AKs4ChDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22dutch%20courage%22&f=false) (1815):

> This vessel proved to be the British letter of marque ship Greenwich, of ten guns, a prime sailer, employed in the whale fishery. Her captain had taken in a good stock of **Dutch courage**, and, from the preparations that were made on board his vessel, there could be no doubt of his intentions to have fired into us, had he not been intimidated by the shot e fired between his masts.

The captain of the Greenwich (John Shuttleworth) is later described as "so much intoxicated, and his language so insulting, that it was with difficulty I [Captain Porter] could refrain from turning him out of my cabin"—so it is clear that Captain Shuttleworth "had taken in a good stock of Dutch courage" internally—and not merely as a provision on board his vessel.

---

***Conclusions***

It is by no means implausible that "Dutch courage" as a fixed phrase may date to the seventeenth century, given the claim in the earliest confirmed match that I could find for it in the relevant sense (from 1781) that as of that date it had already long been proverbial. However, the existence of a popular opinion among British sailors that Dutch seamen took their courage from a bottle, even to the extent of its being viewed as "proverbial," does not require the existence of the exact phrase "Dutch courage" for alcohol-fueled fortitude.

On the basis of the print record that I have seen, it seems quite possible that the precise figurative expression "Dutch courage" arose in the second half of the eighteenth century and that it did not become widespread among English speakers in Britain and North America until the early nineteenth century.

Answer (score 0):

On a tour in London 2012 our guide stated that Durch Courage came about in the rat plague when only Dutch vessels still traded and berthed in the Thames.
The British Government issued  barrell of rum to each Dutch ship that continued to trade, for their Dutch Courage.

Comment: Which "rat plague" would that be?